# int' object has no attribute '__getitem__' Python

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

This is the tree problem

```
    class TreeProblem(Problem):

    # methods exported to Search class ---------------------------------------------    

        # initial "state" of a tree is just its root    
        def initialState(self):
        return self.root.id

        # goal test is whether goal matches node label
        def goalTest(self, state):
        node = self.nodes[state]
        return node.isgoal

        # successors of a node are its children
        def successorFn(self, state):
        node = self.nodes[state]
        if node.isTerminal():
            return []
        else:
            return [self._contents('l', node.lchild), \
                    self._contents('r', node.rchild)]

        # step cost state--[action]-->result is just the random cost associated with result
        def stepCost(self, state, action, result):
        node = self.nodes[result]
        return node.cost

        # no action is actually taken; we just print out the state for debugging    
        def takeAction(self, state, action): 
        print 'visit ', state
            return 'visit', state
```

This is the Node class

```
class Node:
      """A node in a search tree. Contains a pointer to the parent (the node
      that this is a successor of) and to the actual state for this node. Note
      that if a state is arrived at by two paths, then there are two nodes with
      the same state.  Also includes the action that got us to this state, and
      the total path_cost (also known as g) to reach the node.  Other functions
      may add an f and h value; see best_first_graph_search and astar_search for
      an explanation of how the f and h values are handled. You will not need to
      subclass this class."""

      def __init__(self, state, parent=None, action=None, path_cost=0):
          "Create a search tree Node, derived from a parent by an action."
          # state = force_hashable(state)
          self.update(self, state=state, parent=parent, action=action,
                path_cost=path_cost, depth=0)
          if parent:
             self.depth = parent.depth + 1

      def __repr__(self):
         return "<Node %s>" % (self.state,)

      def expand(self, problem):
          "List the nodes reachable in one step from this node."
          return [self.child_node(problem, action)
                 for action in problem.takeAction(self.state, self.action)]
          #print problem
          #return [Node(next, self, act,
           #          problem.stepCost(self.state, act, next[1]))
           #     for (act, next) in problem.successorFn(self.state)]

      def child_node(self, problem, action):
          "Fig. 3.10"
          (act, next) = problem.successorFn(self.state)
          print str(next[1]) + "\n"
          return Node(next, self, action,
                      problem.stepCost(self.state, action, next[1]))

      def solution(self):
          "Return the sequence of actions to go from the root to this node."
          return [node.action for node in self.path()[1:]]

      def path(self):
          "Return a list of nodes forming the path from the root to this node."
          node, path_back = self, []
          while node:
                path_back.append(node)
                node = node.parent
          return list(reversed(path_back))

      def update(self, x, **entries):
          """Update a dict, or an object with slots, according to `entries` dict.
          >>> update({'a': 1}, a=10, b=20)
          {'a': 10, 'b': 20}
          >>> update(Struct(a=1), a=10, b=20)
          Struct(a=10, b=20)
          """
          if isinstance(x, dict):
             x.update(entries)
          else:
             x.__dict__.update(entries)
          return x

      # We want for a queue of nodes in breadth_first_search or
      # astar_search to have no duplicated states, so we treat nodes
      # with the same state as equal. [Problem: this may not be what you
      # want in other contexts.]

      def __eq__(self, other):
         return isinstance(other, Node) and self.state == other.state

      def __hash__(self):
          return hash(str(self.state))
```

This is the dfs_search code:

```
def depth_limited_search(self, problem, limit=50):
          return self.recursive_dls(Node(problem.initialState()), problem, limit)

      def recursive_dls(self, node, problem, limit):
          print str(type(node.state)) + "\n"
          new_state=node.state
          print new_state[1]
          if problem.goalTest(node.state):
             return node
          elif node.depth == limit:
             return 'cutoff'
          else:
             cutoff_occurred = False
             for child in node.expand(problem):
                 result = self.recursive_dls(child, problem, limit)
                 if result == 'cutoff':
                     cutoff_occurred = True
                 elif result is not None:
                      return result
             return if_(cutoff_occurred, 'cutoff', None)
```

here, node.state type is tuple
which has value ('r',2)
when i say node.state[1]

it gives int' object has no attribute '**getitem**' 
the above error
please guide here

Comment: Where is your `node.state[1]` part of the code?

Comment: You *think* `node.state` is a tuple. It is an integer, as the error message quite clearly states. Find out why and fix that.

Comment: see the complete code please now.its a tuple i printed it and saw its type

Comment: Please copy-paste the *exact* output your get from running your code, and add that to your question. Seeing the output of both the print statement and the full traceback helps. (Also, fix the indentation in the second code block, as its slightly confusing, with the indented/nested second `def`.)

Comment: Have you printed `node.state[1]` *before* the assignment to `new_state`?